# Type error cannot read property undefined in angular 8

Tags: angular

> i use angular 8 woth spring Boot, i create a application of
> regestration , when i want to enter details through my font end form
> it accept the value and show null in my database. when i enter data
> through postman it works perfectly. but in front end it show me error
> of this type.

```
:ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
```

> adduser.component.html

```
<h1>Add User</h1>
<form #recievedUser="ngForm">

  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="user name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name">

  <label for="type">Type</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" placeholder="type name" [(ngModel)]="user.type" name="name">

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password">

   <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addUser()">Save</button>
</form>
```

> adduser.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/User';
import { HttpClientService } from '../../../service/http-client.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-adduser',
  templateUrl: './adduser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adduser.component.css']
})
export class AdduserComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  user: User

  @Output()
  userAddedEvent = new EventEmitter();

  newUser: User;
  message: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);

  }

  addUser() {
    this.httpClientService.addUser(this.newUser).subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this.userAddedEvent.emit();
        this.router.navigate(['admin', 'users']);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

> user.componebt.html

```
<h1>Users Admin</h1>
<a class="btn btn-primary mb-3" (click)="addUser()">add</a>
<div class="container row">
    <div   class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users" >
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Details</button></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div   class="col-md-6">
    <app-adduser *ngIf="action === 'add'" [user]="selectedUser" (userAddedEvent)="refreshData()"></app-adduser>
  </div>
</div>
```

> user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientService } from 'src/app/service/http-client.service';
import { User } from 'src/app/User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users:Array<User>;
  selectedUser : User;
  action : String;

  constructor(private httpClientService : HttpClientService,
    private activeRoute : ActivatedRoute,
    private router :Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshData();
  }
  refreshData(){
    this.httpClientService.getUsers().subscribe(
      response => this.handleSuccessfullResponse(response),
    );
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params) =>{
         this.action=params['action']
      }
    );
  }
  handleSuccessfullResponse(response){
   this.users=response;
  }
  addUser(){
    this.selectedUser=new User();
    this.router.navigate(['admin','users'],{queryParams:{action:'add'}});
  }

}
```

> User.ts

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;  
    password: string;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show me whats in `src/app/User` ?

Comment: export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;  
    password: string;
  }

Comment: can u please confirm if my answer worked. If so, please mark it as an answer so that it can be helpful to others and will justify the time I invested in your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in **user.component.ts**

```
addUser(){
    this.selectedUser=new User(); //<- here
    this.router.navigate(['admin','users'],{queryParams:{action:'add'}});
  }
```

you are passing `this.selectedUser` to its child component and then trying to access the value in `form`. Either initialize the value as an object

```
addUser(){
    this.selectedUser= {
      id: 0,
      name: "",
      type: "",
      password: ""
    }
    this.router.navigate(['admin','users'],{queryParams:{action:'add'}});
  }
```

or make changes in class to initialize the values:

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;  
    password: string;
    constructor(){
       this.id = 0;
       this.name = "";
       this.type = "";
       this.password = "";
    }
  }
```